# Find and Replace Duplicate Entries Notepad++

Tags: replace, notepad++

I have generated very large json files and just realized I've produced a duplicate field. Rather than outputting all these files again (very lengthy) I think it would be beneficial if I could just use the Notepad++ find and replace feature to edit them as necessary.

My json fields look like this:

```
{
"PlayerID":44, 
"CurrentTeam":"WAS", 
"Number":95, 
"CurrentAuctionValue":2,
"CurrentAuctionValue":0,
"LastPlayedPoints":0
},
{
"PlayerID":11, 
"CurrentTeam":"WAS", 
"Number":96, 
"CurrentAuctionValue":0,
"CurrentAuctionValue":0,
"LastPlayedPoints":0
},
```

Luckily my generation code for the json always makes the second CurrentAuctionValue 0 but I do not need this field. I would like to get rid of it for convenience sake. It's possible for the auction value to be 0, but only the first CurrentAuctionValue is of importance. Is there any way I can search multiple lines and replace?

Basically in a "code" format I want to do:

```
Find: "CurrentAuctionValue":%d,\n"CurrentAuctionValue":0,\n
Replace: "CurrentAuctionValue":%d,\n
```

I've tried playing with Notepad's search features but have had no success. Suggestions on other methods welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search Mode:  `Regular expression`

Find what:  `("CurrentAuctionValue":\d+),\r\n"CurrentAuctionValue":0,`

Replace with: `$1`

[image]